# How to get this class to call the other class

Tags: java, swing, awt, paint

ok i have 2 classes 
This is my main class it opens a JFrame and draws some stuff to the JFrame:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainWindow extends Canvas{

  public static int HEIGHT = 600;
  public static int WIDTH = 600;

  public static void main(String[] args){
    MainWindow Window = new MainWindow();
    JFrame Frame = new JFrame();
    Frame.add(Window);
    Frame.pack();
    Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Frame.setVisible(true);
    Frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    Frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    Frame.setResizable(false);
    Frame.setTitle("Untitled Build 0.01");
  }
  public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g.drawString("Sellect A Difficulty", 100, 25);
    g.drawString("Please input a number from 1 - 3", 100, 40);
    g.drawString("1. Easy", 100, 55);
    g.drawString("2. Medium", 100, 70);
    g.drawString("3. Hard", 100, 85);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  }
}
```

This is my 2nd class it is for setting the difficulty of the game but i need the main class to call it but i am not sure how to get it to do that.

```
  public class Difficulty {
public static final int input = 0;
static int NoInput = 1;
public static int Difficulty = 0;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void main(String[] args){
    if(NoInput == 1){
        //draw text to screen here
        //TODO Write text to screen here about selecting difficulty
        Difficulty = Keyboard.readInt();
        if(input == 1){
            Difficulty = 1;
        }else if(input == 2){
            Difficulty = 2;
        }else if(input == 3){
            Difficulty = 3;
        }else if(input < 0 | input > 3){
            //TODO draw "please input a number between 1 and 3 try again...." to screen
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For one thing, you probably shouldn't name it `main`. In the meantime, try `Difficulty.main(null)`

Answer (score 2):

Your second class is little more than a program with a single static main method, and this won't work. Suggestions:

- Get rid of the second class and re-write it as a true OOP-compliant class, one with non-static fields, methods, constructors, setters and such.
- Then the first class can have an object of the 2nd and call its methods as need be.
- The second class will need to be a non-console GUI class as well, likely one that produces a JOptionPane.
- Your GUI class should not mix AWT and Swing components, but rather should have just Swing components.
- Read the tutorial "Painting with Swing" to see how to improve your painting.

Comment: Thanks i will go improve it now

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have two main voids? You should be using a constructor for the difficulty class.
Put all of the code into a method like this:

```
public Difficulty() {
   //All your code here
}
```

You may call this method by creating a new instance of this class.

```
Difficulty object = new Difficulty();
```

The constructor will automatically be called when you create the object.

Answer (score 2):

Hovercraft Full Of Eels (nice name btw) already answered this, but I'll add in my 2 cents anyway :P

The second class uses public static void main(String[] args) this implies that it will be run separately.

A quick fix might be to make a constructor for that class, and then calling it via an object.

```
public class Difficulty {
    public Difficulty(){
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Calling it:

```
Difficulty difficulty = new Difficulty();
```

This will call the constructor as soon as the object is created, therefore executing your code when you choose.